# 'SqlConnection' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am starting to learn SQL Server. I want to connect SQL Server using c# but I am getting to following error.

'SqlConnection' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

why am I getting this error?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String baglanti = "Data Source=.; İnitial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection(baglanti);
}
```

Comment: That code seems correct. Are you defining a "namespace SqlConnection" yourself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you've created a project called `SqlConnection` - or have declared a namespace in another project:

```
namespace SqlConnection
{
    ...
}
```

Basically, don't do that - it will make your life harder.

Answer (score 0):

What `namespace` is your code inside, and which `using` directives do you have, and where are they located relative to the `namespace` declaration?

There is some namespace of yours which is found before the intended class `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`.

Use the full name of the type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, edit or move your usings, or rename the boresome namespace you have.